# AJAX call - failling to call do_action

Tags: plugins, ajax

I am trying to make an AJAX call for a plugin.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$.post(
    '<?php admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>',
    {
        action : 'AAA'
    },
    function( response ) {
        alert( "[[[[" + response + "]]]]" );
    }
);
}
```

The ajax call is working fine.

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_AAA', 'fAAA' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_AAA', 'fAAA' );

function fAAA(){
      echo "123";
      die();
}
```

For some reason my fAAA is not getting called.

I used `var_dump( $wp_filter['wp_ajax_nopriv_AAA'] );` to check the actions.
* in the plugin, it showed that the action is added
* when i looked in admin-ajax.php, the action is not there.

Any help?

Answer (score 4):

Aside from @Tareq answer (which is your main problem), you should

- `wp_register_script` and the `wp_enqueue_script`
- load your local copy of jQuery instead of the one from Google CDN
- localize your script using `wp_localize_script`

Answer (score 2):

You didn't echo `admin_url('admin-ajax.php')`

Answer (score 0):

You need to avoid using $ in wordpress, as by default, Wordpress runs jQuery in something called "no conflict" mode. I have learnt to keep to jQuery instead of $ when developing with Wordpress.

I don't know if it's your problem or not, as I'm browsing to find a fix for a problem of my own. You may even know this and be working around it. Apologies if so.

Comment: In this case, $ is passed as an argument to the function. This is one of the methods outlined in the wp_enqueue_script codex page and works correctly in WordPress.